# TypeError: mat data type = 19 is not supported

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, imshow

I'm writing a code that creates a random image. The way I do this is by taking a LOT of different random values and creating a file. The file will than be read and shown via OpenCV. See the example.

```
    def R_Write():
       if os.path.exists("draw_data.pgi"):
          os.remove("draw_data.pgi")
       d_data = open("draw_data.pgi", "w")
       d_data.write("[[[")
       d_data.write(d[1] + " " + d[2] + " " + d[3]+ "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[4] + " " + d[5] + " " + d[6] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[7] + " " + d[8] + " " + d[9] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[10] + " " + d[11] + " " + d[12] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[13] + " " + d[14] + " " + d[15] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[16] + " " + d[17] + " " + d[18] + "]]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "[[" + d[19] + " " + d[20] + " " + d[21] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[22] + " " + d[23] + " " + d[24] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[25] + " " + d[26] + " " + d[27] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[28] + " " + d[29] + " " + d[30] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[31] + " " + d[32] + " " + d[33] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[34] + " " + d[35] + " " + d[36] + "]]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "[[" + d[37] + " " + d[38] + " " + d[39] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[40] + " " + d[41] + " " + d[42] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[43] + " " + d[44] + " " + d[45] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[46] + " " + d[47] + " " + d[48] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[49] + " " + d[50] + " " + d[51] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[52] + " " + d[53] + " " + d[54] + "]]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "[[" + d[37] + " " + d[38] + " " + d[39] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[40] + " " + d[41] + " " + d[42] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[43] + " " + d[44] + " " + d[45] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[46] + " " + d[47] + " " + d[48] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[49] + " " + d[50] + " " + d[51] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[52] + " " + d[53] + " " + d[54] + "]]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "[[" + d[55] + " " + d[56] + " " + d[57] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[58] + " " + d[59] + " " + d[60] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[61] + " " + d[62] + " " + d[63] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[64] + " " + d[65] + " " + d[66] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[67] + " " + d[68] + " " + d[69] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[70] + " " + d[71] + " " + d[72] + "]]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("\n")
       d_data.write(" " + "[[" + d[73] + " " + d[74] + " " + d[75] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[76] + " " + d[77] + " " + d[78] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[79] + " " + d[80] + " " + d[81] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "..." + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[82] + " " + d[83] + " " + d[84] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[85] + " " + d[86] + " " + d[87] + "]" + "\n")
       d_data.write("  " + "[" + d[88] + " " + d[89] + " " + d[90] + "]]]")
       d_data.close()
       d_data = open("draw_data.pgi", "r").read()
       print(d_data)
       Draw(d_data)

  def Draw(data):
          cv2.imshow("Random_Pixels", np.array(data))
```

But then the error occurs TypeError: mat data type = 19 is not supported. How do I convert it to a other type or how do I resolve the problem?

I already tried a couple of things like,

```
    data_2 = np.int16(data)     # convert to signed 16 bit integer to allow overflow
    data_2 = scale_factor*data_2 # apply scale factor
    data_2 = clip(data_2, 0, 255) # force all values to be between 0 and 255

    # after clip img2 is effectively unsigned 8 bit, but make it explicit:
    data_2 = np.uint8(data_2)
```

please help me? I am really motivated for this project and I would like to continue it, but I can't without your help.

Comment: Do you know how pgi files are supposed to look? I don't but what you are writing is just a textual representation of a matrix. I doubt that is the correct format, as that is _way_ more verbose than any normal image format I know of.

Comment: As first step, I'd consider whether something like [`cv2.randu`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga1ba1026dca0807b27057ba6a49d258c0) or [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) already does what I need. If not, i'd consider using loops instead of copy-pasting the same thing over and over and over and over with increasing indices.

Comment: @johanL .pgi is a made up ending to distinguish between multiple files. .pgi for me is a file where I store data to later be read again for use. eventually the .pgi file is read at the end of the R_Write function and is saved. Later it will be called in the cv2.imshow("", data) function. that's when the error data type = 19 is not supported occurs.

Comment: That said, it seems you write into a text file what looks like immitation of the output you get when you print out a 3-channel numpy array... including the `...` placeholder it uses for skipped rows/columns when the array is too large. Then you read the file back into a single string, create a `numpy.array` from it (which makes it an array with a single string), and then try to display that using `imshow`. It seems that you have misconceptions about how most of the things you've used work (reading files, numpy arrays, imshow).